# RESTful Controller without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do this:

```
namespace :user do

  namespace :builder do
    resource :general_info, only: [:edit, :update]
    resource :biography, only: [:edit, :update]
  end

  root to: 'profiles#edit_biography'
end
```

So that I can get those nice RESTful controllers:

```
general_info_controller
biography_controller
```

But probably bad idea to create dummy `builder` model.

Without it these controllers give an error:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder::BiographiesController
```

Answer (score 1):

The model is only accessed by the controller's implementation and optionally the view if the controller sets such a variable like @mymodel. The restfulness comes from the behavior which is the interface of the controller's methods: index, push, pull, create, etc, whatever you want. The routing mechanisms are very powerful and flexible that you can recreate any convenience of the 'resource' routes yourself.

```
namespace :user do
   namespace :builder do
      get "edit" => "somecontroller#edit"
```

... kind of thing. It is up to you how you decide to implement the edit implementation and whether that needs any model at all. You can also control the view that is shown with render.

Yes, this violates the rails conventions, but so what, they are just conventions which are only applicable when they are applicable. Not every problem will fit all the defaults.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Normally resources have ids that map to a database. They would have routes defined like

```
get ":id/edit" => "resourcecontroller#edit"
```

It isn't clear to what degree you need to replicate the model resource paths by your question.

Comment: See my comment on your post. REST is an http convention, and dictates no specific implementation or pattern, and certainly doesn't require Rails or any Rails specific convention. REST is a behavior, in Rails, you provide behavior in controllers. Yes, commonly some behavior is delegated to models, but that isn't required.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the best way is using a Model. I suggest you this book

> Service-Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails (Addison-Wesley Professional Ruby Series) [Paperback] 
>   [http://www.amazon.com/Service-Oriented-Design-Rails-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321659368](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368)

If you are using RESTful with Database, the best practice is with a Model to better data control.

Comment: You are just promoting following the rails convention but the question asks how to do it otherwise.